# XmlSerializer deserialize class hierarchy

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I got some issues with the XmlSerializer in .NET.

Here I have a small example I built up just right now. (also available @ gist https://gist.github.com/2d84be9041a3f9c06237)

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XmlSerializingSample
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var specialType = new SpecialType()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "test"
                };

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (SpecialType));
            var des = new XmlSerializer(typeof (BaseType));
            using (var memeStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(memeStream, specialType);
                memeStream.Flush();

                memeStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var instance = des.Deserialize(memeStream); // Here it throws the exception
            }
        }
    }

    [XmlInclude(typeof(SpecialType))]
    [XmlType("baseType")]
    public class BaseType
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("special")]
    public class SpecialType : BaseType
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In line 24 of the code I get an InvalidOperationException stating  "{"<special xmlns=''> wurde nicht erwartet."}" [yes, it's german]

All Posts I found stated, after adding XmlIncludeAttribute on the base type being deserialized, this should work. Did I forget sth.?

Regards,
MacX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your Serializer is serializing the SpecialType with a root element as so:

```
<special ...>
   <Id>...
```

But then you try to Deserialize it using  `var des = new XmlSerializer(typeof (BaseType));` it knows about both types but it doesn't know how to handle the `root` element in the xml.

If you want this to work, you need to also set the root element of the base type to serialize as `special`. In other words, you would need to do this:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(SpecialType))]
[XmlType("baseType")]
[XmlRoot("special")]
public class BaseType
{
      public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

That way, the deserializer knows how to handle `special` as the root element.

I don't think there are other simple alternatives to make this work out of the box.

## Update

This is another alternative using the [XmlAttributeOverrides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlroot.aspx) class.

LinqPad code:

```
void Main()
{
      var specialType = new SpecialType()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "test"
                };

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (SpecialType));

            XmlAttributeOverrides attrOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
            XmlAttributes attrs = new XmlAttributes();

            // Create an XmlRootAttribute to override.
            XmlRootAttribute attr = new XmlRootAttribute();
            attr.ElementName = "special";

            // Add the XmlRootAttribute to the collection of objects.
            attrs.XmlRoot=attr; 
            attrOverrides.Add(typeof(BaseType),  attrs);
            var des = new XmlSerializer(typeof (BaseType), attrOverrides);

            using (var memeStream= new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(memeStream, specialType);
                memeStream.Flush();

                memeStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var instance = des.Deserialize(memeStream); 
            }

}

[XmlInclude(typeof(SpecialType))]
[XmlType("baseType")]
public class BaseType
{
      public long Id { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("special")]
public class SpecialType : BaseType
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Problem is in case, that I don't take part within the serialization. I only got the xsd-file. And many different implementation of "SpecialType". And you can't apply multiple XmlRootAttributes on a Type

Comment: @MacX yes, you can do this. There's a way to override the XmlRootAttribute. I'm posting a full sample. I hope it helps.